# three.js - How to change background using WebGLDeferredRenderer

Tags: background, three.js

Can't seem to find how to change a background color when using WebGLDeferredRenderer.

renderer.clearColor = 0xff0000; doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WebGLDeferredRenderer is just a wrapper for WebGLRenderer, you can access the functions of WebGLRenderer via WebGLDeferredRenderer.renderer e.g.:

```
renderer.renderer.setClearColor(clearColor);
```